# Debug referenced project added to solution

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I have a "core" project I am working with and, to use some functionality from another project, I have added this one to my solution and use the `Imports` statement to import it into the "core" project.

However, during the dubugging process I cannot debug line-by-line the added project. It jumps into a class, but jumps over most of it, ending up in my 'core' project.

For example, here is a a class in the project that was added:

[image]

Even with setting breakpoints I can debug (yellow marking lines) the first three lines but then the debugger jumps into my main code (within the core project).

Is there a way I can debug the added project, as normal. At the moment, I created a new project, copied everything from both projects into it, and debug it there, and that works, but that's obviously not a permanent solution.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  Solutions contain projects, not the other way around.  You can't add a solution to a project.  Please edit your question and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you actually did.

Comment: Correctly... I missed solution and project up... I added an example and hope I can express the problem better

Comment: @ruedi are you sure that you're executing line by line and not statement after statement?

Comment: As I said, at the moment I copy the not working code into a new Solution and there I can just debug it line by line. I substituted the example with a probably better one. In this example I can debug it line by line in the test-solution but when I want do debug it in the upper explained structure it debugs until the second line and from there it jumps into the core project.

Comment: The problem is probably that your one project has a _file reference_ to the other rather than a _project reference_.  Try removing the reference and re-adding it as a project reference.

Comment: You may want to make sure you haven't selected Copy Local = False in the settings for the project reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug that project you need to have the pdb file. When you compile the other project, you will see that you have the dll file and a pdb file in the debug folder. Take that pdb file and copy it to the debug folder of your main application and you should be able to debug the project, unless you have added some attributes to avoid debugging to the original function (debuggerstepthrough).

Comment: If the project is part of the solution, then this should be happening automatically.

Comment: Sure, but he did not mention that it was part of the solution when he asked the question. At the beginning it seemed it was a file reference which still probably is according to his problem description.

Comment: But then the real problem is that it's a file reference where a project reference was intended, and the missing pdb file is just a symptom.